# Qt WinRT app crashes when changing title bar color

Tags: c++, qt, c++-winrt

I want to create the `WinRT` app using Qt. I use `Qt 5.15.8`. The issue is when I add the following code to change the app title bar color:

**.h file**

```
#include <winrt/Windows.System.Diagnostics.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.ViewManagement.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::System::Diagnostics;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Windows::UI::ViewManagement;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;
```

**.cpp file:**

```
auto titleBar = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView().TitleBar();
titleBar.BackgroundColor(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 54, 60, 116));
titleBar.ForegroundColor(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 232, 211, 162));
```

The program just exits (crashes):

```
22:28:32: Debugging C:\Qt\5.15.8\winrt_x86_msvc2019\bin\winrtrunner.exe "C:\Users\cobra\Documents\Projects\UWP\build-TestUWP23-Desktop_Qt_UWP_5_15_2_MSVC2019_32bit-Debug\debug\TestUWP23.exe" --install --verbose ...
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(1) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(1) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(2) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(2) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(3) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(3) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(4) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(4) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(5) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(6) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(7) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(8) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(9) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(10) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(11) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(12) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(13) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(14) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(15) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(16) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(17) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(18) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(19) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(20) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(21) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(22) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(23) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(24) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(25) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(26) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(27) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(28) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(29) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(30) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(31) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(32) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(33) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(34) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(35) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(36) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(37) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(38) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(5) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(39) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(40) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(41) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(6) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(42) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(43) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(44) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(7) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(45) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(46) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(47) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\consumption\src\packagereaderhelper.cpp(193)\AppxPackaging.dll!66A924B9: (caller: 66A8B243) LogHr(8) tid(5228) 80080203 The file is not a valid Appx package because it is missing a manifest or block map, or missing a signature file when the code integrity file is present.
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(48) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(49) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
onecore\printscan\appxpackaging\blockmap\src\appxblockmapreader.cpp(517)\AppxPackaging.dll!66AE50E4: (caller: 66A92443) ReturnHr(50) tid(5228) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    Msg:[Filename: AppxContentGroupMap.xml] 
22:28:50: Debugging of C:\Qt\5.15.8\winrt_x86_msvc2019\bin\winrtrunner.exe "C:\Users\cobra\Documents\Projects\UWP\build-TestUWP23-Desktop_Qt_UWP_5_15_2_MSVC2019_32bit-Debug\debug\TestUWP23.exe" --install --verbose has finished.
```

I run the debugger but it still the same, the app just exits. I checked for dump file but no dump is present in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\CrashDumps`. It's just simple app, can someone reproduce it?

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent)
    : QDialog(parent)
{
    QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click", this);
    btn->setGeometry(250, 400, 100, 100);
    connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]() {
        ApplicationView appView = ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView();

        if (appView) {
            qDebug() << "Success!";
            auto titleBar = appView.TitleBar();
            titleBar.BackgroundColor(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 54, 60, 116));
            titleBar.ForegroundColor(ColorHelper::FromArgb(255, 232, 211, 162));
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Failed!!!";
        }
    });
}
```

It just exits whithout any return from `ApplicationView` instance.

**Screenshot:**
https://i.ibb.co/cbRzxHB/Qt-Win-RT-app-issue.gif

```
17:37:53: Starting C:/Qt/5.15.8/winrt_x86_msvc2019/bin/winrtrunner.exe "C:\Users\cobra\Documents\Projects\UWP\build-TestUWP23-Desktop_Qt_UWP_5_15_2_MSVC2019_32bit-Debug\debug\TestUWP23.exe" --install --verbose...
qt.winrtrunner: Using the Appx profile.
qt.winrtrunner: Package already installed.
qt.winrtrunner: App started with process ID 11952
qt.winrtrunner: Unable to sendFile: Cannot open C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Packages\066dc9bf-27bd-4f3e-abbc-06652d5ce6ce_qqv8ky19h7t4c\LocalState\TestUWP23_output.txt for input
qt.winrtrunner: Unable to copy test output file "C:\Users\cobra\AppData\Local\Packages\066dc9bf-27bd-4f3e-abbc-06652d5ce6ce_qqv8ky19h7t4c\LocalState\TestUWP23_output.txt" to local file "TestUWP23_output.txt".
17:37:58: C:/Qt/5.15.8/winrt_x86_msvc2019/bin/winrtrunner.exe exited with code 9
```

I have Windows 10 Version 22H2 installed. Developer mode is enabled. Any ideas why this code leads to such issue? Thank you.

Comment: The code never checks whether `ApplicationView::GetForCurrentView()` returns anything. Make sure you read the remarks on [`ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview#windows-ui-viewmanagement-applicationview-getforcurrentview).

Comment: @IInspectable
Hello!
I have tried to run it on button click. I will provide the example. It still does exits (crashes).

Comment: @IInspectable
Ok. I updated the main post. Also, I added the screenshot to illustrate this issue. Thank you.